# passing datestring to date command using xargs failing

Tags: macos, date, xargs

I am trying to use MacOS date to subtract 5 minutes from a date which is passed using xargs but its failing as follows:

```
$ echo '"2021/02/25 09:20:28"' | xargs -0 -t date -j -f \'%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S\' -v \'-5M\'
date -j -f '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S' -v '-5M' "2021/02/25 09:20:28"

Failed conversion of ``%H:%M:%S''' using format ``'%Y/%m/%d''
date: illegal time format
usage: date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ...
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
```

However when I run a command printed by xargs that is totally working fine

```
$ date -j -f '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S' -v '-5M' "2021/02/25 09:20:28"
Thu Feb 25 09:15:28 IST 2021
```

Please suggest how to fix this?

Comment: Why `-0`, why do you use double quote in the date? Did you check the number of single quote?

Comment: If I don't use double quote in date, xargs passes it as two arguments with space and date command fails

Comment: @ShashwatKumar `xargs -0` does not parse quotes; with the `-0` option, it just treats quotes as part of the data. You might need the double-quotes if you didn't use null-delimited fields, but using both together doesn't make any sense. What's the larger context here? That is, why are you needing to use `xargs` in the first place?

Comment: @GordonDavisson Any other way to pass string to date command using pipe?

Comment: Do you need to use a pipe, or could you include the source command in `"$(srccommand)"`? (Note: If you *really* needed to use it in a pipe, `srccommand | date ... "$(cat)"` would work.)

Comment: my srccommand is multiline output and I want date to run for each of them.

Comment: You want to run `date` for each line? That sounds like a job for `srccommand | while read line; do date ... "$line"; done`. Again, more complete context would help.

Comment: @ShashwatKumar Thanks for the acceptance. You can say thanks by up voting the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution for your example command with echo:

```
echo "2021/02/25 09:20:28" | xargs -I {} -t date -j -f '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S' -v -5M {}
```

The resulting output is:

```
date -j -f %Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S -v -5M 2021/02/25 09:20:28
Thu Feb 25 09:15:28 EST 2021
```

Note:

- You don't need the -0 because your echo is terminating the date with
  a \n character.
- You can remove the -t when done testing.

If your dates are indeed going to be sourced with nulls (\0) between the dates, you will need to re-enable the -0 option.